# System Maintenance Tool?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, 64-bit, windows-registry

Is there a tool you guys would recommend I install on a new 64-bit win7 system that would allow me to keep my registry clean, keep my drivers up-to-date etc?

Comment: You chose the best answer about 10 minutes after posting the question. Does that imply you don't want any more responses or options?

Comment: No, actually I guess that's some bad form - I'm still interested in more feedback and options. Sorry, kind of new to asking questions here.

Answer (score 3):

An all-in-one? I don't know of a good one. If you don't mind 2 separate tools, I'd recommend [CCleaner](http://ccleaner.com) and [DriverMax](http://www.drivermax.com/).

Comment: I accepted this as the best answer ten mins after posting my question but comments above made me realize I should leave it open a little bit yet. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

[jv16 powertools](http://www.macecraft.com/jv16powertools2009-info/) - although not free, after trying it, I've never looked for anything else.

[image]

Comment: +1 been using this and its predecessors for a few years now without issues

Answer (score 0):

Before you install any programs, install **[Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/)**.

This will monitor further software installation and remove the programs completely (unlike the regular Windows uninstaller).

[image]

As for an all-round cleaning/maintenance tool for Windows 64-bit, I can recommend **[Advanced SystemCare Free](http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-SystemCare-Free/3000-2086_4-10407614.html)**: a one-click approach to help protect, repair, clean, and optimize your PC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While not *exactly* what you're after, one of the first tools I install on my machines is [Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/). It is very helpful in letting me know when I have apps with security issues and usually offers a link to the app's site to get a current/patched version.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Windows 7 Manager](http://www.yamicsoft.com/windows7manager/index.html) by YamicSoft. It's a good set of maintenance tools and it's trial is free for 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

[TuneUp Utilities 2010](http://www.tune-up.com/products/tuneup-utilities/)

[image]

*This is not freeware*